# Preencher números faltantes de uma sequência

Tags: php, array-multidimensional

Olá,
Estou montando um sistema de estatísticas.
O resultado é um Array com "hora" e "views".
Preciso incrementar estes dados com as 24 horas do dia para que o gráfico fique completo.

```
    $sql = "SELECT HOUR(data) as hora, COUNT(id) as views "
            . "FROM trafego "
            . "WHERE data >= '{$periodo}' "
            . "GROUP BY hora ";

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    $result = $query->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

O RESULTADO QUE TENHO É

```
     0 =>
          object(stdClass)[4]
          public 'hora' => string '1' (length=1)
          public 'views' => string '3' (length=1)
     1 =>
          object(stdClass)[5]
          public 'hora' => string '4' (length=1)
          public 'views' => string '3' (length=1)
     2 =>
          object(stdClass)[6]
          public 'hora' => string '8' (length=1)
          public 'views' => string '5' (length=1)
     3 => 
          object(stdClass)[7]
          public 'hora' => string '10' (length=2)
          public 'views' => string '4' (length=1)
     4 =>
          object(stdClass)[8]
          public 'hora' => string '11' (length=2)
          public 'views' => string '7' (length=1)
     5 =>
          object(stdClass)[9]
          public 'hora' => string '21' (length=2)
          public 'views' => string '3' (length=1)
     6 =>
          object(stdClass)[10]
          public 'hora' => string '22' (length=2)
          public 'views' => string '3' (length=1)
```

Como incrementar esta array com as horas e adicionar 0 views?

Exemplo, eu tenho os horários 1, 4, 8, 10 ,11, 21, 22

Preciso adicionar horários faltantes e esses devem ter 0 views

```
hora    views
1    -> 3
2    -> 0 (faltante, por isso deve ser 0)
3    -> 0 (faltante, por isso deve ser 0)
4    -> 3
```

Assim segue até 24 horas. (0 ~ 23)

Comment: Não entendi o que deseja incrementar em horas... Pode dar um exemplo do resultado que deseja?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução é primeiro criar um array com todos os horários desejados e valores zerados, depois basta atualizar o array com os valores que você possui. Abaixo o código que mostra isso:

```
// O resultado obtido do banco de dados
$result = [
    (object)['hora' => 1, 'views' => 3],
    (object)['hora' => 4, 'views' => 3],
    (object)['hora' => 8, 'views' => 5],
    (object)['hora' => 10, 'views' => 4],
    (object)['hora' => 11, 'views' => 7],
    (object)['hora' => 21, 'views' => 3],
    (object)['hora' => 22, 'views' => 3]
];

/*
 * Inicia a estatística com todos os horários possíveis e com valores zerados.
 *
 * O segredo é utilizar a hora como chave do array,
 * isso facilita o preenchimento dos horários conhecidos na próxima etapa.
 */
for ($hora = 0; $hora < 24; $hora++) {
    $estatistica[$hora] = (object)['hora' => $hora, 'views' => 0];
}

/*
 * Atualiza a estatística com os horários que possui views.
 *
 * Aqui você deve percorrer o resultado do banco,
 * também deve ser utilizada a hora como chave para acessar
 * o item correspondente no array que atualmente está zerado
 * e atualizar a quantidade de views pelo valor real.
 */
foreach ($result as $horario) {
    $estatistica[$horario->hora] = $horario;
}

// Mostra o resultado
echo '<pre>';
print_r($estatistica);
echo '</pre>';
```

O resultado será:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hora] => 0
            [views] => 0
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hora] => 1
            [views] => 3
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hora] => 2
            [views] => 0
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hora] => 3
            [views] => 0
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hora] => 4
            [views] => 3
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hora] => 5
            [views] => 0
        )

    [6] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hora] => 6
            [views] => 0
        )

    [7] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hora] => 7
            [views] => 0
        )

    [8] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hora] => 8
            [views] => 5
        )

    [9] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hora] => 9
            [views] => 0
        )

    [10] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hora] => 10
            [views] => 4
        )

    [11] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hora] => 11
            [views] => 7
        )

    [12] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hora] => 12
            [views] => 0
        )

    [13] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hora] => 13
            [views] => 0
        )

    [14] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hora] => 14
            [views] => 0
        )

    [15] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hora] => 15
            [views] => 0
        )

    [16] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hora] => 16
            [views] => 0
        )

    [17] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hora] => 17
            [views] => 0
        )

    [18] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hora] => 18
            [views] => 0
        )

    [19] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hora] => 19
            [views] => 0
        )

    [20] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hora] => 20
            [views] => 0
        )

    [21] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hora] => 21
            [views] => 3
        )

    [22] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hora] => 22
            [views] => 3
        )

    [23] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hora] => 23
            [views] => 0
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
Array de teste. Existe apenas 1, 4, 8 e 11
*/
$result = array(
    0 => (object)array(
        'hora' => 1,
        'views' => 3
    ),
    1 => (object)array(
        'hora' => 4,
        'views' => 3
    ),
    2 => (object)array(
        'hora' => 8,
        'views' => 3
    ),
    3 => (object)array(
        'hora' => 11,
        'views' => 3
    )
);

$data_new = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 24; $i++) {
    foreach ($result as $k => $v) {
        if ($v->hora == $i) {
            /*
            Atribui o valor existente a um novo array
            Isso também garante que a ordem dos horários seja igual as chaves array.
            */
            $data_new[$i] = $result[$k];

            /*
            Apaga essa chave para evitar percorrer novamente esse valor em todas as iterações.
            Como o horário é único, não tem com o que se preocupar.
            */
            unset($result[$k]);

            /*
            O amado e odiado "goto".
            Se a linguagem disponibiliza esse recurso, presente em muitas linguagens, por que não usá-lo?
            O uso aqui simplifica uso de break e uma flag para pular também a iteração principal.
            */
            goto next;
        }
    }

    /*
    Atribui 0 views para um horário inexistente.
    */
    if (!isset($data_new[$i])) {
        $data_new[$i] = (object)array(
            'hora'=>$i,
            'views'=>0
        );
    }
    next:
}

/*
Mostra o resultado
*/
print_r($data_new);
```

Resulta nisso

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hour] => 0
            [views] => 0
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hour] => 1
            [views] => 3
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hour] => 2
            [views] => 0
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hour] => 3
            [views] => 0
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hour] => 4
            [views] => 3
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hour] => 5
            [views] => 0
        )

    [6] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hour] => 6
            [views] => 0
        )

    [7] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hour] => 7
            [views] => 0
        )

    [8] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hour] => 8
            [views] => 3
        )

    [9] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hour] => 9
            [views] => 0
        )

    [10] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hour] => 10
            [views] => 0
        )

    [11] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hour] => 11
            [views] => 3
        )

    [12] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hour] => 12
            [views] => 0
        )

    [13] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hour] => 13
            [views] => 0
        )

    [14] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hour] => 14
            [views] => 0
        )

    [15] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hour] => 15
            [views] => 0
        )

    [16] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hour] => 16
            [views] => 0
        )

    [17] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hour] => 17
            [views] => 0
        )

    [18] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hour] => 18
            [views] => 0
        )

    [19] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hour] => 19
            [views] => 0
        )

    [20] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hour] => 20
            [views] => 0
        )

    [21] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hour] => 21
            [views] => 0
        )

    [22] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hour] => 22
            [views] => 0
        )

    [23] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hour] => 23
            [views] => 0
        )

)
```